# How can I use Apple Music without my iCloud Library?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music, apple-music

1. There's no "reset iCloud library" button on my account.
2. I still want to put 2 albums, that are on my PC, on my phone (they aren't on Apple Music, I've already searched), but when I enable iCloud Library, which  has like 900 songs that I don't want on my cell, there's no way to put them on my phone.

I'd like to reset my iCloud Music Library, however I do not know how to or see an obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to your problem is to set up direct synchronization between your PC and your phone. Once that happens, you can manually synch the two albums to your phone from your PC using iTunes.

[Setting up iPhone to iTunes syncing](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12313)

Once that happens, resetting your iCloud music account won't be necessary.